# How to save value from JQuery $.post to a Javascript Global Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using Javascript and JQuery.

I have the following Variable `var RoleID="";` and I have placed it outside of all functions.

I have a function

```
role_submit(){
var role=$('#emp_role').val();
var url="submitrole.php";
$.post(url, {role2: role} ,function(data){
var RoleID=data;
alert(RoleID);
})
}
```

This function gets the value of an `<input type="text" id="emp_role">` and submits to a `url='submitrole.php'` using JQuery `$.post` and gets back an **ID** from `url='submitrole.php'` in return which is saved in `RoleID` and afterwards `RoleID` is alerted. This all is executed using `<button onclick="role_submit();" type="submit">Submit</button>` and works fine meaning that the **ID** which should come from `url='submitrole.php'` comes accurately and is also alerted accurately.

***The issue arises when I use following function to look at the global variable*** `var RoleID`

```
function alert_roleID(){alert(RoleID);}
```

I call to this function using

`<button onclick="alert_roleID();" type="submit"  >Role ID</button>`

This time the alert pops up showing nothing rather than the **ID** I got back from `url='submitrole.php'`. How can I get the global variable `RoleID` to have the value of from `url='submitrole.php'`?

Comment: you `post` callback function defines a locally scoped RoleID which isn't the same as the globally scoped RoleID - that's how javascript works - remove `var` in the callback, and you will be updating the global RoleID

Comment: @ jaromanda X 

Thanks a lot. this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

Set the variable to the window explicitly. [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is the global scope.

```
function role_submit(){
  var role=$('#emp_role').val();
  var url="submitrole.php";
  $.post(url, {role2: role} ,function(data){
    window.RoleID=data;
    alert(RoleID);
  })
}
```

Or define the variable in the global scope. If you do it this way, make sure you don't use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) when you redefine it. If you use `var` it makes a new variable only visible in that scope (function).

```
var RoleID;
function role_submit(){
  var role=$('#emp_role').val();
  var url="submitrole.php";
  $.post(url, {role2: role} ,function(data){
    RoleID=data;
    alert(RoleID);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you declared the variable outside, you should not use 'var' once again inside the function since this will recreate the local scoped variable instead of a global scoped variable and inaccessible outside the function. So you can remove the 'var' as below,

```
var RoleID = '';

role_submit(){
var role=$('#emp_role').val();
var url="submitrole.php";
$.post(url, {role2: role} ,function(data){
   RoleID=data;
alert(RoleID);
})
}
```